# Threading C# lot slower then expected

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

We have a problem with importing data with usage of threads for speeding up process, but we can't figure it out, so we broke it down to pieces.

At beginning, we had a data source with 1 million rows with artificial primary key, we suppose to take data, convert it to XML and insert it into another data source. Idea was to have more threads, split rows equally per each thread and do the job, parallel work should speed up process overall, right? But it wasn't like that, so we focused only on splitting rows per thread, convert it to XML and append it to some Data Table within memory to calculate time.

Here is what we do:

```
private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread MyThread = new Thread(Action_Start);
    MyThread.Start();
}

void Action_Start()
{
    string _Threads = text_Threads.Text;    // obtaining amount of threads 
    string _Bucket = text_Bucket.Text;      // obtaining amount of rows to 
                                            //          process per thread

    List<Task> MyTasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int Index = 1; Index <= Convert.ToInt32(_Threads); Index++)
    {
        int MyIndex = Index;
        MyTasks.Add(
            Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => DoWork(MyIndex, Convert.ToInt32(_Bucket))));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(MyTasks.ToArray());
}

async void DoWork(int p_Index, int p_Bucket)
{
    DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();

    for (int Index = 1; Index <= 20; Index++)
    {
        DataColumn MyColumn = new DataColumn("FIELD_" + 
                                  Index.ToString("0000"), typeof(String));
        MyTable.Columns.Add(MyColumn);
    }

    for (int Index = 1; Index <= p_Bucket; Index++)
    {
        DataRow MyRow = MyTable.NewRow();

        for (int Index2 = 1; Index2 <= 20; Index2++)
        {
            string MyField = "FIELD_" + Index2.ToString("0000");
            MyRow[MyField] = new String('0', 128);
        }
        MyTable.Rows.Add(MyRow);
    }

    Stopwatch MyTimer = new Stopwatch();
    long Brojac = 1;
    DataTableReader MyReader = MyTable.CreateDataReader();

    MyTimer.Start();

    while (await MyReader.ReadAsync())
    {
        string Result = "<Root>";
        for (int Index = 1; Index <= 20; Index++)
        {
            string MyField = "FIELD_" + Index.ToString("0000");
            XElement MyXml = new XElement("Property");
            MyXml.SetAttributeValue("Value", MyReader[MyField]);
            MyXml.SetAttributeValue("Field", MyField);
            Result += MyXml.ToString();
        }
        Brojac++;
        Result += "</Root>";
    }

    MyTimer.Stop();
    MyReader.Close();

    TimeSpan ts = MyTimer.Elapsed;

    //TIPS_AND_TRICKS: How to format and display the TimeSpan value.
    string elapsedTime = String.Format
                         ("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", 
                          ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);

    string Buffer = "Processing time: " + 
                     elapsedTime + "; Through-put: " + 
                     Convert.ToInt32(Brojac / ts.TotalSeconds).ToString() + 
                     " records per second; Total " +
                     p_Bucket.ToString("000000 ") + " records";
    Poruka(Buffer);
}
```

So biggest problem here is that when we run :

`1 thread for 50.000 rows; processing time is 00:00:05.49; On average 9099 records per second;`

vs

`4 threads for 50.000 rows (12.5k per thread); average processing time per thread is 00:00:20.80; On average 2390 records per second;`

My question is, why processing time and rows on average is going down once we use more threads and tasks? Aren't they suppose to go in parallel and just devour this data set in matter of milliseconds?

Comment: It might be that your string concats consumes that "extra"-time. My advice is to use a StringBuilder object and repeat the measurement .. but it's a lot of code and that's just an idea.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior in a simpler, verificable example (see [mcve])? The way it is, depends on too much implementation details and is quite hard to analyze. I believe that there is some kind of locking going on, preventing your tasks going as fast as possible. You should really get yourself a profiler and conduct a root cause analysis, because everything we could tell you would be guesswork.

Comment: So where is the time going? What did you measure? Have you run your code through a profiler? Guessing where code runs slow is something developers are really really bad at. Measure, measure, measure, then when it doesn't make sense, get back to us.

Comment: A thread spawning tasks which do synchronous stuff asynchronously, oh my. First of all, consider writing this as a `Parallel.ForEach` or a parallel LINQ `.AsParallel()`; that's already far simpler than cutting up things manually. Second, instead of immediately going to parallelism, take a look at what you're doing and whether it can't already be sped up on a *single* thread. For starters, `DataTable` is a very inefficient class because it deals with untyped data. Second, streaming data is typically more efficient than doing a huge conversion of everything at once.

Comment: `Result += MyXml.ToString();` is going to cost you in the case of many appends, but this probably isn't your biggest problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointers, @JeroenMostert Idea of this is to go for million of rows, that's why we keep with multithreading, this was just a test case, also we will check to change to `Parallel.ForEach`, thanks for that idea!

Comment: @spender I am sorry for coming without more measurement, still bad at this and all I could think off was using a stopwatch class and come up with some type of numbers to have `as measurement`, will check more about C# profiling and see what's going on there

Comment: @Veljko89 It's really important to measure. I would also take on-board what @JeroenMostert wrote. Are you dealing with threads or tasks? Do you need to deal with any, given `Parallel.ForEach` etc.?

Comment: If your code is very allocation-heavy (as the code you currently have is) then just throwing more threads at it is no guarantee of a decent speedup, because the garbage collector does not parallelize too brilliantly. Do not focus on "oh but we have MILLIONS of rows" right up front; make sure your individual slices of work are as smart as possible before you start threading. For instance, if your target data source does not (currently) allow parallel inserts, then speeding up the XML conversion may largely be a waste of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments, the main bottleneck for your application is the garbage collector, because you're doing a lot of allocations.

A profiling session with dotTrace shows 30% of time spent in the GC. That's **huge**:

[image]

The main source of allocations is the XmlWriter that gets allocated when you call `MyXml.ToString()`. If performance is a concern, you should consider other ways to generate the XML. For instance, replacing the thing by a `string.Format` shows a 5x performance improvement on my machine.

Comment: Thanks man!!! replacing it with `string.Format` actually did improved speed and overall process by mile!